# Joystick USB definition for use with Arduino

Tags: arduino, hid, joystick

I'm trying to write the control code for a custom joystick, and I cannot find any reference to what needs to be implemented to be recognized by a computer as a joystick.

I can see what things I need to have by referencing various game library APIs for using a joystick.

For example, `pygame` has the following methods,

```
init
quit
get_init
get_name
get_id
get_numaxes
get_numbuttons
```

etc.

My next stop is to read through the kernel for Linux's [HID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device) and joystick controlers... But this seems like a really round about way of finding this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked with it, but it looks like there is some interesting information in *[Arduino Uno Joystick HID firmware](http://hunt.net.nz/users/darran/weblog/a3599/)* and *[Arduino Uno Big Joystick HID firmware](http://hunt.net.nz/users/darran/weblog/15f92/)*. There is also  [UnoJoy](http://unojoy.tumblr.com/About) - I'd try that first (assuming you have an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) or [Leonardo](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardLeonardo)).